# Assume integer divison

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question that requires me to find if a function is one to one and if it is onto assuming the domain & co-domain are Z.

One of the functions has the following added to it "Assuming integer division" what does that mean?

The function is f(X) = X/2

Comment: It means you are to discard the fractional part of your result.  Thus $f(3)=1$, for example.  see, e.g., [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) for a reference.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it, and I guess it makes sense since that case f(1)=0 and f(-1)=0 making it not one-to-one

Comment: I would argue that $f(-1)=-1$, as $-1$ is the greatest integer not exceeding $-\frac 12$.  But of course $f(0)=0$ so your conclusion is valid.

Comment: To elaborate:  I've seen people use different conventions for integer division when negatives are involved.  I, like @par below, would say that $\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor$ was intended, and $\lfloor -.5\rfloor=-1$.  But I have seen people "round toward $0$".  The context really should specify which is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integer division, they might mean $f(X)=\left\lfloor X/2\right\rfloor$, though it's hard to say for sure. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).